# Multiple fields in one cell with SuperCSV

Tags: java, supercsv

I have one table with some columns:

```
 UserID | FirstName | LastName | Email
```

I want to write these columns to a CSV with **SuperCSV** in JAVA.

But I want to write them like this:

```
 UserID | FullName | Email
```

I mean that I want to concatenate the first name with the last name and show it as fullName. but I don't know how and I can't find anything explaining.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to add a new getter to the identity.

I added this new getter to the User identity and it works perfectly:

```
public String getFullName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Very simple and logic after all..